# Storing large text in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm implementing a web app with an App Engine backend. The server should consist of few servlets.

One of the servlets reads and processes some data and then saves the output - a text. The servlet is rarely called and the output text is rarely changed. The output (in a form of a json file) should be then accessed from a web page by means of another servlet - it would happen frequently. The max size of the output text is smaller than 1 MB.

I have some ideas how to do it, but I would appreciate some hints. Especially, what is the best way to store the output text? And how to effectively implement both servlets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The servlet that changes the text should save this in the database. The servlet that serves the text should serve from a cache that doesn't expire very frequently.

Comment: Well, such general answer isn't much helpful. I was interested in some hints about a good way how to implement storage of a large string (<1MB) in database.